# Conjugate Nets in Higher Dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, nets

Consider the following definition of conjugate nets in arbitrary dimensions (in the following $3 \leq N$ and $2\leq m < N$).

**Definition:** An immersion $f: \mathbb{R}^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ is called an $m$-dimensional conjugate net in $\mathbb{R}^N$ if at every point $p$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and for all pairs $1 \leq i \neq j \leq m$ one has $\partial_i\partial_j f \in \textrm{span}(\partial_i f, \partial_j f)$ where by $\partial_i f$ we mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$.

In the book [Discrete Differential Geometry](https://books.google.at/books/about/Discrete_Differential_Geometry.html?id=2YmaAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), the author claims that a generic surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$ has a unique conjugate net and in higher dimensions such a parametrization does not need to exist at all.
Up to my knowledge the author does not provide any proof or reference to the claim (so I suspect this must be a classical result).
Therefore, my questions are

1. How to prove the claim (a proper reference would suffice too),
2. Is it possible to have a geometric description for the case of $\mathbb{R}^4$? Similar to what already exists for the Dupin Indicatrix of regular surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (see [conjugate diameter of conics](http://www.grad.hr/geomteh3d/skripta/konj_promjeri_eng.html))?